# Samsung Grand mobile Not showing UI but I can see UI in emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to deploy app on Android device But I am not able to see the UI. My device configuration as below

Handset : Samsung Grand 
OS : Android 4.2 (API 17)

in project properties I set the application Tab like this

[image]

please let me know what wrong with it. Similar configuration for Android Emulator I cab able to see the UI.

Comment: Did you try setting the **Minimum Android to target** to the API lower than which your device supports. e.g setting it to API 16. Verify this in the manifest also `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />`

Comment: @AkashAmin Done with same changes but not able to deploy to device.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: it just deploy and stop only I can see the Icon not the UI. when app launch its stop immediately.

Comment: @AkashAmin no such error. its just display me name of an App.

Comment: Im talking about the error in the output window.@MartinP

Comment: @AkashAmin 05-16 17:39:16.004 F/monodroid-assembly(  422): Could not load assembly 'Rad' during startup registration.
05-16 17:39:16.004 F/monodroid-assembly(  422): This might be due to an invalid debug instalation.
05-16 17:39:16.004 F/monodroid-assembly(  422): A common cause is to 'adb install' the app directly instead of doing from the IDE. such error

Comment: Try creating a apk in release mode and then install the apk manually.

Comment: @AkashAmin I solve the issue. set project in release mode its work Thanks for your help...

Comment: @AkashAmin thanks for help

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct to close this thread.

Comment: Are you still having the debug releated problem? @MartinP

Comment: Try unistalling apk from device first before installing again. This works for me with same samsung device. Sometimes device restart is also required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a apk in release mode and then install the apk manually.